# C#: Adding data to List which must contain coordinates

Tags: c#, .net, list, coordinates

My problem is that I don't know how to add data to list and keep my coordinates (I must use list not array).

Here is the code where I should add data to list by keeping coordinates(i, j):

```
 for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) //x = amount of vertical lines
 {
     for(int j = 0; j < y; j++) //y = length of one line
     {
         //labyrinth[i][j] is the string type list
         //intLabyrinth is int type list
         if (labyrinth[i][j] == '.') intLabyrinth.Add(0);
         if (labyrinth[i][j] == '#') intLabyrinth.Add(-1);
         if (labyrinth[i][j] == '@') intLabyrinth.Add(1);
         if (labyrinth[i][j] == '%') intLabyrinth.Add(-2);
     }
 }
```

So how can I fix it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What list do you need to add something to? And is that data the coordinates? [MCVE]

Comment: What do you mean by "keep my coordinates"? Keep how? Where? Why?

Comment: If `intLabyrinth` is the list you are talking about you are already doing it.

Comment: Yes, but I must have coordinates like in array for exp. array[i][j] = value . Later in code  I need to access it

Comment: Do you mean, you want to store coordinates i.e. x and y in a list? `List<Tuple<int,int>>` should be `intLabyrinth `?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store multiple values in your list, in this case you can use a `Tuple`

Redefine your list as follows:

```
//i, j, value
List<Tuple<int,int,int>> newLabyrinthList = new List<Tuple<int,int,int>>();
```

And than add, in the order you want (I use i,j,value in this example)

```
if (labyrinth[i][j] == '.') newLabyrinth.Add(new Tuple<int,int,int>(i,j,0));
if (labyrinth[i][j] == '#') newLabyrinth.Add(new Tuple<int,int,int>(i,j,-1));
if (labyrinth[i][j] == '@') newLabyrinth.Add(new Tuple<int,int,int>(i,j,1));
if (labyrinth[i][j] == '%') newLabyrinth.Add(new Tuple<int,int,int>(i,j,-2));
```

You can retrieve the values using, for example:

```
int i = newLabyrinth[0].item1;
int j = newLabyrinth[0].item2;
int v = newLabyrinth[0].item3;
```

or from a loop

```
foreach(var tuple in newLabyrinth)
{
    int i = tuple.item1;
    int j = tuple.item2;
    int v = tuple.item3;
}
```

If this is to obscure you could define a class to store in your list:

```
public class OperationAtCoordinate
{
    public int X {get;set;}
    public int Y {get;set;}
    public int Operation{get;set;}
}
```

Then you'll need a list like:

```
List<OperationAtCoordinate> newnewLabyrinth = new List<OperationAtCoordinate>();
```

Add by calling:

```
newnewLabyrinth.Add(new OperationAtCoordinate()
                    {
                       X = i,
                       Y = j,
                       Operation = //your value here
                    });
```